# Altering objects in Unit Testing?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to test a class. Doing so, I'm changing the objects state, yet for some reason, that change is only temporary.

Here is what I mean:

```
class ownerTest {

Owner Tom = new Owner(); // creates owner and initializes arraylist of type pet
Pet Doggy = new Pet("Rexy"); // creates pet object doggy

@Test
public void test1() {
    Tom.addPet(Doggy); //will add doggy on to tom's arraylist
    assertEquals(Doggy, Tom.petList.get(0)); // passes
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    assertEquals(Doggy, Tom.petList.get(0)); // fails cause arraylist is empty
}
```

I've been told that I can treat test classes much like normal classes. Then why are changes made to objects in test units only temporary?

Would love some clarification.

PS: The equals method has been adjusted accordingly so it's not about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I realize I must be getting something completely wrong. I'm a bit confused about how I should approach testing so excuse my knowledge gaps. I'm overall very new to coding.

Comment: JUnit creates a new instance of the test class for each test.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but do not capitalize the first letter of variable names, that should reserved for _class_ names.  Example: `thisIsVariableName` and `ThisIsClassName`.  I recommend looking up Java naming conventions.

Comment: Hey @Nexevis , I appreciate it! I will make sure to follow up on your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then why are changes made to objects in test units only temporary?

The state of the object/fixtures under test has a scope that fits to the tests scenario requirements.
Why do you want that changes performed during a test has a side effect on the next executed tests ?
With such a permissivity, you are not able to know why a test fails and why a test succeeds since any test may change the result of others.

So definitively, each test method have to be not coupled with others.
And here, that is perfectly valid that the test fails  :

```
@Test
public void test2() {
    assertEquals(Doggy, Tom.petList.get(0)); // fails cause array is empty
}
```

Generally a test method tests a public.protected method of the class under test or else a specific scenario for one of these methods. So `test1()`, `test2()` are bad naming choices.

For example :

```
@Test
public void add_and_get() {
    Tom.addPet(Doggy); //will add doggy on to tom's arraylist
    assertEquals(Doggy, Tom.petList.get(0)); 
}

@Test
public void get_when_not_existing_returns_null() {
    assertNull(Tom.petList.get(0)); 
}
```

> I've been told that I can treat test classes much like normal classes.

And that is right. Test classes matter and have to be handled as first-class citizen since these live the whole life of the application and they provide the  automated regression tests, the living documentation and the quality general of your application.

Comment: I actually don't, that's exactly why I was getting confused by somebody saying I can treat these as normal classes. Thanks david! EDIT: Yes, I know. The example I put in SO is not my actual class, just a depiction of what I'm trying to do. I do try to name my tests accordingly :).

Comment: You have to  treat them as normal classes. That is right. I updated to explain that point. You are welcome :)